# How to fix plastic hinges, or prevent them from breaking?

Tags: storage, repair, camera, cell-phone

It's all too common that plastic flaps on various devices and storage containers break off.

Over time, the thin plastic hinge gets weak from repeated use, and snaps.  A common place this seems to happen is on pill containers, since they are typically opened and closed at least once every day.  Another common place is on cell phones, tablets, and digital cameras that have plastic flaps protecting their ports.

Is there a life-hacky way to fix this when it happens, or prevent it from happening in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I would add a few layers of clear adhesive tape (like Scotch tape) over the hinges while they're still working properly. The tape is flexible.  It should reinforce the hinge a bit.  And if the hinge breaks, the tape will keep acting as a hinge in its place.

EDIT: @DangerZone points out that packing tape is more durable than Scotch tape. Cut strips of packing tape to the correct width before you stick them over your plastic hinges.

Comment: Scotch tape can be pretty bad at holding up for long periods of time. I think something like packing tape would be better.

Comment: The best stuff I have found for stuff like this is clear Scotch™ #845 Book Tape which is made to flex indefinitely. Be warned that it's expensive. Next best is Crystal Clear (a tape) that is sold in Canada at Canada Post outlets will not tear and grips almost as well as book tape.